# How to save TextInput with it's defaultValue if the user hasn't changed anything?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Okay so I hope this is easy, but I can't find anything about that on Google.

I have a details screen for a (cooking)receipe in my app. With the tap of a button the user can set a state `isEditing`, which then converts a heading into a text input. That heading displays `{receipe.title}` and I use the same value for the `default value` prop on the text input.

Once the user taps the edit button again, `isEditing` will be set to false and a update function will update the receipe in my Firebase database.

```
{!isEditing ? (
  <Text style={styles.headingLarge}>{receipes.title}</Text>
):(
  <TextInput 
      placeholder='Titel'
      autoFocus={true}
      defaultValue={receipes.title}
      style={styles.headingLarge}
      onChangeText={text => {
        setPresentTitle(text);
      }}/>

)}
```

It's all working, as long as the user actually changes something in the input. But the issue is that if a user doesn't change anything, `onChangeText` is never called and the database is updated with an empty string as it's title.

Is there a way to call the `onChangeText` when setting the defaultValue for this input (or another hack to set the `setPresentTitle`)?

Comment: I hope, I understood your question well.
for this problem, you need a helper state to save the last input of the user. if the user doesn't change anything you can send the last input to firebase.

Comment: The issue I‘m trying to solve is that the user never changed the input - the input is set with the defaultValue prop and then never touched. 

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can check this snack out, ive made it for you

This is the snack : https://snack.expo.dev/@gaurav1995/fascinated-donut

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

```js
import React,{ useState ,useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View ,TextInput ,Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  const receipes = {
      title:"Hey there"
    }

    const [isEditing, setEd] = useState(false)

    const [text,setPresentTitle] = useState(receipes.title) 


 
    

    const toggleEdit = () => {
      setEd(!isEditing)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      //update to firebase
      //setFirebase(text)
    },[text])
    
  return (
   <View>
  {!isEditing ? (
  <Text style={styles.headingLarge}>{text}</Text>
):(
  <TextInput 
      placeholder='Titel'
      autoFocus={true}
      value={text}
      style={styles.headingLarge}
      onChangeText={text => {
        setPresentTitle(text);
      }}/>

)}

<Button title="Toggle Edit" onPress={toggleEdit} containerStyle={{marginTop:20}} />
   </View>
    )

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    padding:40
  },
  headingLarge:{
    fontSize:40,
    marginBottom:20
  }
})
```

Comment: Hi Gaurav, many thanks for your reply! The idea to include the updated function into the useEffect was the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: glad it helped ate

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I made a mistake - the answer isn't working. I don't know what I did when answered, but I'm still facing the old issue. I have it set up exactly like it is in your setup, only difference is that my receipes is loaded from Firebase and I have my `update(ref(db, xxx))` outside the useEffect. Now if I switch to edit mode,  don't touch any input and back to normal mode, the update fails because my title = undefined. Do you have any idea why that could be?

Comment: Okay nevermind, I just had an idea (and it worked): I just replaced the value for updating when it's undefined, like so: `title: presentTitle === undefined ? receipes.title : presentTitle`

Comment: yeah, you should do that until its undefined